# How to get the document line?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm creating a tool that works with file strings and I need to get the line number where a node is found. It is, I have this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//text()") as $q) {
    // $line = WHAT???
    $strings[trim($q->nodeValue)] = $line;
}
```

and I need to know in which line begins the string I'm storing in `$strings` array. Is it possible to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/DOMNode) object has a [`getLineNo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/domnode.getlineno.php) function that returns this. In your case it's a [`DOMText`](http://php.net/DOMText) object that extends from `DOMNode`:

```
foreach ($xpath->query("//text()") as $q) {
    $line = $q->getLineNo();
    $strings[trim($q->nodeValue)] = $line;
}
```

You might need to upgrade to PHP 5.3 if you have not yet to make use of that function.

Comment: [Apparently this method is buggy](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php#usernotes), especially for text nodes.

Comment: I get a wrap-around here, e.g. line 65536 is 0, 65537 is 1 etc. Using PHP 5.3.10 on Windows XP 32 bit or some PHP 5.4 on Linux 64 bit. I'd say this relates to the libxml version and type of compile used. As https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676026 states, it's a limitation in the SAX library.

Comment: @lanzz: The related PHP Bugreport is: [Bug #54138 DOMNode::getLineNo() doesn't return line number higher than 65535](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54138), I've listed some more resources as a comment there, this bug is probably not worth to fix it. If you don't think so, you can engage yourself in the libxml2 project which takes care of the underlying library and accepts patches.

Comment: You are right, I have no interest in working on fixing libxml2 bugs, which means that this issue does not exist and OP should ignore it. `</sarcasm>` I'm not implying your answer is wrong, but it is still an issue that should be pointed out.

Comment: Well I don't mean to ignore it because of something is not fixed. This is a limitation in libxml2, the question is if this turns out to be a problem for the question. I'd say this bug would have been patched already if it would have been worth the proble, because it was already reported and discussed ca. 5 years ago. And normally this should not be a problem. But thank you for pointing to it, I also tried to add more useful information to the PHP bugreport.

Comment: Well, I'll accept the answer because even with the limitation exposed it's useful taking some precautions. Thanks

Comment: Leave a note if this does not turn out to work practically. We might need to add some better workaround as the one given on the php.net manual page.